# Медленный полнотекстовый поиск mysql

Tags: mysql

Приветствую.

Сразу к делу. Структура таблицы такая:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `board` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_user` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `cat` mediumint(2) NOT NULL,
  `podcat` tinyint(3) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `name_translate` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `file` char(50) NOT NULL,
  `foto` char(50) NOT NULL,
  `fotka` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `screen` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `size` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `size_convert` char(10) NOT NULL,
  `price` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `telefon` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `contact` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `send` enum('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `city` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `adress` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `skype` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `time` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `timeupdate` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `timesrok` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `top` enum('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `toptime` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `srochno` enum('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `timesrochno` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `vydelit` enum('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `timevydelit` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `torg` enum('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `by` enum('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `free` enum('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `status` enum('0','1','2') NOT NULL DEFAULT '2',
  `convert` enum('0','1','2') NOT NULL DEFAULT '2',
  `type` enum('1','2') NOT NULL,
  `activation` enum('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `count` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `text` varchar(5000) NOT NULL,
  `prosmotrov` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `lat` char(11) NOT NULL,
  `lng` char(11) NOT NULL,
  `watermark` enum('0','1') NOT NULL,
  `latp` char(11) NOT NULL,
  `lngp` char(11) NOT NULL,
  `deletetime` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `delcount` enum('0','1') NOT NULL,
  `folder` enum('0','1') NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `podcat` (`podcat`),
  KEY `status` (`status`),
  KEY `activation` (`activation`),
  KEY `timesrok` (`timesrok`),
  KEY `cat` (`cat`),
  KEY `city` (`city`),
  KEY `top` (`top`),
  KEY `count` (`count`),
  KEY `id_user` (`id_user`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `search1` (`name`, `text`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `adress` (`adress`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

SQL запрос

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS `board`.*, (SELECT `id_board` FROM `favorites` WHERE `favorites`.`id_board`=`board`.`id` AND `id_user`='".$user['id']."' LIMIT 1) AS `fav`,
    (SELECT `name` FROM `cat` WHERE `cat`.`id`=`board`.`cat`) AS `cat_name`,
    (SELECT `name` FROM `cat` WHERE `cat`.`id`=`board`.`podcat`) AS `podcat_name`,
    (SELECT `translate` FROM `city` WHERE `city`.`name`=`board`.`city`) AS `translate`,
    (SELECT `namer` FROM `city` WHERE `city`.`name`=`board`.`city`) AS `city_r`,
    (SELECT `translate` FROM `cat` WHERE `cat`.`id`=`board`.`cat`) AS `cat_translate` FROM `board` WHERE `cat`='".$cat['id']."' AND `status`='1' AND `top`='0' AND `activation`='0' AND `timesrok`>'".$realtime."' AND MATCH (name, text) AGAINST ('".rawurldecode(htmlspecialchars(trim($_COOKIE['search'])))."' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Записей в таблице более 160 тысяч. Поиск по name и text выполняется 2 секунды. Можно это дело как то ускорить?

Answer (score 2):

Сначала про ответ выше. Он *очень* странный.
Хотя вопрос про *выборку* данных, автор зачем-то делится своим опытом про *вставку*. И очень, видимо, гордится тем, что сумел забить микроскопом 50 гвоздей за два часа.

При том что "добавление 1к строк с 10ю ячейками в каждой" занимает меньше 0,1 секунды даже на самом древнем железе.

А проблему с медленной вставкой в innodb надо решать **штатными** средствами. Например - обернув все вставки в **транзакцию**. И тогда без всяких мультизапросов все вставится в мгновение ока.

Теперь к вопросу.
Чтобы ускорить медленный полнотекстовый запрос, надо оптимизировать медленный полнотекстовый запрос. То есть, запрос, в котором есть только полнотекстовая выборка **и больше ничего.**

В таком случае мы можем говорить, что медленный у нас именно полнотекстовый запрос. А если у нас на него накручено еще 100500 красивостей, то утверждать, что проблема именно в полнотекстовом поиске, нам не позволит банальная логика.

Ну и плюс здесь таки может сыграть негативную роль select.* в сочетании с `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS`, но я бы на это не полагался.

В любом случае, для поиска (а тем более многофакторного) рекомендую Сфинкс.

Comment: Без поиска по name и text запрос выполняется 0.5с. Тоже довольно долго.

Comment: То есть "полнотекстовый поиск" здесь всё-таки не при чём?

Comment: Возможно. Выполнил EXPLAIN, скрин ниже.

Answer (score -1):

Можно использовать асинхронные запросы к БД. Тут об этом более подробно написано - http://habrahabr.ru/post/155377/

Я добавление 1к строк с 10ю ячейками в каждой, сократил с 50сек до 5.

Ох, @Nicolas, написана целая статья, я не буду ее здесь пересказывать. На хабре не удалят, я уверен.
По поводу того, что MYSQLI_ASYNC не ускорил, то он и не ускорит, просто добавление флага это будет то же самое, что вызвать curl_multi_init и инициализировать один дескриптор. 
Нужно создать пул запросов к БД. Пример:

```
$sql= request();
$a = $a + 1;
$sql.= request();
$a = $a + 1;
```

Где request() возвращает команду запроса, а $a - счетчик(в моем случае сдвигал смещение при запросе(можно еще как ключ массива использовать. и потом командой

```
$mysqli->multi_query($sql)
```

выполняем запрос.

Я, для такого увеличения /* добавление 1к строк с 10ю ячейками в каждой, сократил с 50сек до 5 */ Использовал 500 потоков.

Для лучшего ознакомления с темой, лучше почитать статью или погуглить "асинхронные запросы MySQL".

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение? Добавьте в ответ минимальный необходимый пример решения (информацию по ссылке могут удалить и ответ потеряет ценность ).

Comment: После добавления в sql-запрос, который выше, MYSQLI_ASYNC не увеличил скорость выполнения самого запроса.

Comment: Там статья-то, 2-х экранов нет. Заметка скорее. А удалить её могут, автора забанят и статья пропадёт. Хабр не очень надёжное место, в этом плане.

Comment: Результат EXPLAIN http://joxi.ru/Rmzz90VunWNamO на всякий случай.